# Defining a sequence with two parameters

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to define a sequence for the Proth numbers (these are numbers of the form $h\cdot 2^k+1$ for a natural $k$ and an odd $h<2^k$).
I want it ordered at first by the exponent, then by the coefficient.
So I get the sequence $(a_n)_n = (1\cdot 2^1 + 1, 1\cdot 2^2+1, 3\cdot 2^2+1, 1\cdot 2^3+1\dots).$

But I am really uncertain how to note it.
I thought about
$$
(a_{k,h})_{k\in\mathbb N \\ 1\leq h \leq 2^k-1, h \text{ odd}}.
$$

This looks too much, but I have another problem:
If I use double indices, I can't say "the $5-$th number".
I must say "the (3,3)-th number".

Is there a way that I can write it down and still refer to an element as the $n$-th element?

Comment: Yes, but it's messy. You might want to look at the Josephus numbers first: https://oeis.org/A006257 ; these give you the sequence of $h$ values you want. The final indexing will be something like the one you can see on the linked page.